# Cual es la diferencia entre el operador de indirección y el operador de dirección en el lenguaje C?

Tags: c, punteros, operadores

Estoy utilizando punteros en el lenguaje C y necesito explicar la diferencia entre  el operador de indirección y el operador de dirección.

Comment: pues creo que existen varios ejemplo en la web solo investiga un poco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador de indirección se representa con un asterisco `*` y se utiliza para operar sobre punteros y acceder a los valores a los que estos apuntan.

En cambio el operador de dirección se representa con una 'y' comercial `&` y se utiliza sobre variables de cualquier tipo para obtener su dirección.

Por ejemplo:

Esto es una variable de tipo entero

```
int x;
```

Esto es un puntero a un entero

```
int *px;
```

Se da el valor 5 a x

```
x = 5;
```

Utilizando el operador de dirección se guarda en px la dirección de la variable x

```
px = &x;
```

Aqui a través del operador de indirección se assigna el valor 10 en la dirección a la que apunta px,

```
*px = 10;
```

Esta última sería lo mismo que haber asignado directamente el valor 10 a la variable x ya que px apunta a x

```
x = 10;
```